# Is it possible to reverse probabilistic automaton?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

Is it possible to reverse probabilistic automaton (PA), i.e. calculate the probability of previous state given current state? Will reversed automaton be a PA (Markov?), i.e. will next probability depend on current state only? If not, then what it will be?

Comment: Are you talking about PA a-la Segala and Lynch? Then the choice of labels also matters the distributions, so in general it is not a Markov Chain, but rather and MDP which can be history-dependent, so no hope for the time reversing. I also think, this question better fits [tcs.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry not familar with Segala and Lynch :shame: I mean just state machine which changes it's state according to probability transition matrix.

Comment: Do you allow for a non-determinism there? Namely, if you're in state $i$ then you have several successor distributions $P^a_{ij}$ and $P^b_{ij}$ or just one?

Comment: Distribution is one, but it includes several successor states, i.e. $P_{ij}$ can be greater than zero for more than one $j$-s

Comment: Ok, then it falls completely into the case of Markov Chains for which the reversibility is characterized in the answer by Bunder below.

Answer (score 1):

Reversibility of a Markov Chain is not always possible. There is a characterization though, if the chain is irreducible (i.e. every state can be reached from any other state) with the stochastic matrix $P$ and the initial probability $\lambda$ vector satisfying the "detailed balance equations":
$$ \lambda_i p_{ij} = \lambda_j p_{ji}$$
the chain is reversible. In particular this implies that $\lambda$ is a invariant probability measure, so reversibility can't always happen.

Comment: Aren't both sides identical up to index names?

Comment: @SuzanCioc: no, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reversible_Markov_chain)

Comment: A necessary condition to be reversible is that $\{(i,j)\mid p_{ij}\ne0\}$ and $\{(i,j)\mid p_{ji}\ne0\}$ coincide.